# Clojure: laziness + core.logic: infinite loop

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

### Context

The following code infinite loops:

```
(defn ex13 []
  (take 5
        (run* [x]
       (listo (lcons `a (lcons `b (lcons `c x)))))))
```

### Question:

Is this supposed to be the right behavior? (infinite looping?) On the other hand, code like:

```
(take 5 (range))
```

takes 5 elements and prints them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug, however that's not the right way to do it as the results of run* are not truly lazy anyhow.

```
(run 5 [x]
   (listo (lcons `a (lcons `b (lcons `c x)))))
```